# Paraview: coloring by position vector?

Tags: colors, paraview

I have an unstructured grid (with `VTK_VERTEX` cells) and I would like to colorize the points by their spatial position vector (or its components). I could save position data in each point as an array, but that would be a considerable amount of redundant data. Something more straightforward?

Answer (score 0):

That's what you have to do currently, I am afraid. Using `Programmable Filter`, you can add the point coordinates array to PointData without doing a *deep-copy*, hence there won't be a memory overhead. If you simply use the `Calculator`, however, it will create a new array.

Comment: Thanks. How would I do that with Calculator? I am not concerned about memory, more about unnecessary disk storage use.

Comment: Using the expression `coords` should do the trick. You can also select it using the **Vectors** button.